# How to change pointSize of a font in Qt?

Tags: qt, styles, stylesheet, qtstylesheets

I would like to change the font's pointSize but nothing happens. It's always the same point size.

Does someone know how to change the pointSize of a font in Qt Style Sheet?

This is the used code :

```
QPlainTextEdit
{
border-color:transparent;
border: 0px;
color: white;
font: 10pt "Webdings";
font.pointSize: 113;
}
```

Comment: This is in the [stylesheet reference docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html). See the `font-size` property.

Comment: it wokrs. thank you!